# How to add custom view in navigation bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to create the custom view on my navigation bar.I have three items on the navigation bar.On the left i want to add UIImageView just after that a UILabel & to the right a UIImage.Now i have added right bar button to the right from storyboard & added image.I want to add Imageview & UILabel to the left side.Please tell how can i add this so that gap is maintained properly.

[image]

Comment: you can add it programmatically to`self.navigationController?.navigationBar`

Comment: if you are trying just to adjust the position of the navigation bar title, then you can set a UILabel as the title view, `self.navigationItem.titleView = <UILabel>`

Answer (score -1):

```
//FETECH BUTTON IMAGES FOR BOTH STATES NORMAL AND SELECTED
var normal= UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FIRSTBUTTONIMG", ofType: ".png" , inDirectory: "FOLDER_PATH")!);

normal = normal?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

var selected = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FIRSTBUTTONIMGSELECTED ", ofType: ".png" , inDirectory: "FOLDER_PATH")!);

selected = selected?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

let Fbutton = UIButton(type: .Custom);

Fbutton.setImage(normal, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Fbutton.setImage(selected, forState: UIControlState.Selected)

Fbutton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(YOURBTNACTION(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

Fbutton.frame=CGRectMake(0, -6, 53, 53)

//ADD YOUR CUSTOM VIEW AND ADD ABOVE BUTTON INSIDE CUSTOM VIEW
let CustomView = UIView()

CustomView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, Fbutton.frame.height, Fbutton.frame.width);

CustomView.addSubview(Button)

//ADD MORE ITEMS  TO CUSTOM VIEW IF NEEDED

//ADD THAT CUSTOM VIEW TO UIBarButtonItem

let CustomViewButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backCustomView)

//ASSIGN THAT UIBarButtonItem TO leftBarButtonItems AS ARRAY ITEM
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems=[CustomViewButton,MORE ITEM IF NEEDED];
```